# JSP unbalanced custom tag

Tags: jsp, custom-tags

I am trying to conditionally display a custom tag like so:

```
<c:if test="${condition}">
  <my:mytag>
</c:if>

My content here

<c:if test="${condition}">
  </my:mytag>
</c:if>
```

If the condition is true then I want the content to be inside mytag. Otherwise I want the content to be plain. Assume the content can be complex and contain other tags.

Unfortunately, when I try to run this code I get an error saying: 'The end tag "</my:mytag" is unbalanced'.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to achieve using JSP?

Answer (score 0):

no, it still needs to be valid XML.

The whole thing needs to be wrapped by a single `<c:if>` block.

Comment: But if <my:mytag> is replaced with an <h1> tag then the example works. But that doesn't seem like valid XML.

Comment: Interesting.  I haven't used JSP in a while to recall whether it has special handling to html elements.

Comment: @priomsrb.. its Incorrect. you cannot have a closing tag of </h1> within if or any of that matter. but an opening tag will just be fine